# Pythonic way to wrap a subprocess call that takes a lot of parameters?

Tags: python, subprocess, parameter-passing, args, keyword-argument

I am writing a python script that provides a more user friendly API to a command line tool. Some of the necessary command calls take a lot of parameters (up to around 10 sometimes), but that is not good practice in Python. They can't just be defaults; it has to be possible to set all the parameters for a given call.

My current structure is an API class that has functions such as expose_image(), and then an interface class to handle the construction of the subprocess command and the call. I don't see that adding more classes will help, as the API class still has to generate and pass the parameters in some way.

One solution I have come up with is to fill a dictionary or namedtuple with the parameters and pass it as **kwargs, which makes things look a little nicer, but less explicit.

Is there a better way of handling this?

Thanks!

Comment: can you what have is your class structure in code itself

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is commendable that you want to build a Pythonic API rather than just an API for this command.

I'm not sure why you disregard default parameters though? If the default is `None`, you could treat that as a guide to not add things to the command line.

For example, suppose you want to call the tree command. You could have something like:

```
def my_tree(dirs_only=False, full_prefix=False, max_level=None, pattern=None):
   cmd_line = ['tree']
   if dirs_only:
       cmd_line.append('-d')
   if full_prefix:
       cmd_line.append('-f')
   if max_level is not None:
       cmd_line.append('-L')
       cmd_line.append(str(max_level))
   if pattern is not None:
       cmd_line.append('-P')
       cmd_line.append(pattern)
   subprocess.do_something_with(cmd_line)
```

Callers of `my_tree` could then interact with it like in the shell:

```
my_tree()
my_tree(dirs_only=True)
my_tree(pattern='Foo*')
my_tree(pattern='Foo*', max_level=2, full_prefix=True)
```

In languages such as Java, C# or Dart, you often see "fluent" APIs, and perhaps those might help. It would result in code such as:

```
my_tree().call()
my_tree().dirs_only().call()
my_tree().with_pattern('Foo*').call()
my_tree() \
    .with_pattern('Foo*') \
    .with_max_level(2) \
    .full_prefix() \
    .call()
```

Though the invocation looks nicer, there is a lot of boilerplate you need to write in order to obtain said niceity, which definitely feels a little bit un-Pythonic.

Comment: I am _fairly_ happy to just use defaults. Your example looks pretty clean, but using that style with 10 parameters could get quite hard to understand. So I wondered if there might be a better way. Would you suggest that method over a dictionary as **kwargs?

Comment: @GDYendell: The beauty of using keyword args is that you can pass the function args as a dict using the `**kwargs` syntax if you want. Or you can do a combination, with some args passed explictly in `keyword=value` form and the rest in a dict. Unfortunately, you can't specify a keyword arg that's also mentioned in the kwargs dict, or you get a `TypeError` "got multiple values for keyword argument".

Comment: @PM2Ring That is a good point; it's nice that you don't have to choose between the two.

Comment: @GDYendell if the function has to be called with 10 arguments, then it's going to be a complex call no matter how you arrange things - positional arguments, defaults, **kwargs, defaults+**kwargs, fluent etc. If you know that users are going to have some specific needs, perhaps have some helpers such as my_tree_prefixed('Foo*') or my_tree_special('Foo', 2), which hide some of the complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Like you said, `**` of kvargs are convenient way to *pass* several arguments to your function, however it always better to declare arguments explicitly in the function definition:

```
def store(data, database,
          user, password,
          host=DEFAULT_HOST,
          port=PG_DEFAULT_PORT,
          chunk_size=64,
          flags=None):
     pass

# call
params = {"data": generate_data(),
          "database": "mydb",
          "user": "guest",
          "password": "guest",
          "chunk_size": 128
          }
store(**params)
```

Another way is to use "Parameters" class, like this (an example from `pika` library):

```
class ConnectionParameters(Parameters):

    def __init__(self,
                 host=None,
                 port=None,
                 virtual_host=None,
                 credentials=None,
                 channel_max=None,
                 frame_max=None,
                 heartbeat_interval=None,
                 ssl=None,
                 ssl_options=None,
                 connection_attempts=None,
                 retry_delay=None,
                 socket_timeout=None,
                 locale=None,
                 backpressure_detection=None):

        super(ConnectionParameters, self).__init__()

        # Create the default credentials object
        if not credentials:
            credentials = self._credentials(self.DEFAULT_USERNAME,
                                            self.DEFAULT_PASSWORD)
        ...
# call
conn_params = pika.ConnectionParameters(host=self._host,
                                            port=self._port,
                                            credentials=cred)
conn = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters=conn_params)
```

Comment: Yeah, I think I am going to define the options explicitly in the function definition regardless of using **kwargs or keyword=value. Would using that Parameters class add anything that a nametuple wouldn't do?

Comment: @GDYendell No, if you don't need to implement any logic (may be some checks?) or have a hierarchy of 'Parameters" - then namedtuple is even better for you.